# How to display row values from jtable into jtextfields where my jtable is inside a jscrollpane

Tags: java, jtable, jscrollpane

I want to get action listener on my jtable where my jtable is inside or i am using jScrollpane . I tried not using jscrollpane and i was able get a mouse listener but i want to get a mouse listener when i'm using jscrollpane with jtable.

[image: Here it is]

heres my code when clicking the jtable

```
    private void jTable1MouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                     
        // TODO add your handling code here:
        System.out.println("click");
        DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel)jTable1.getModel();
        int selectedRowIndex = jTable1.getSelectedRow();
        fname.setText(model.getValueAt(selectedRowIndex, 1).toString());
    }
```

Comment: Umm, why not just use a button to perform the action? Also its not really clear what data you want to display. Only the data you selected or what exactly?

Comment: I already tried doing it with buttons but I also want to try this one .only the data that is selected or the row that is selecte/click.

Comment: You should add that to your question. Also provide example code for the GUI and data